# Digital Audio Processing on the iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, audio, compatibility, signal-processing, iphone-4

We've been working with some digital audio signal processing here and we've recently become worried that the iPhone 4S might not behave like the iPhone 4 did.

For instance: we have an app that listens to a specific sound and works on it. However, the data generated by the sound, while pretty constant in the iPhone 4, varies a lot in the iPhone 4S. Even though it is the same sound every single time, the data pattern seems to be randomly different.

Another (maybe) important information: from what I can see from my tests, by now, the iPhone 4S doesn't seem to work well with frequencies above 20.5 kHz (the iPhone 4 works very well until 21.5 kHz).

My question is: did anyone already go through something like this? Are the iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S recording systems that different? Is this a hardware situation and/or should the software be modified to support it?

I know that those may not be proper questions, but I don't really know where to go right now, to be able to achieve some kind of diagnosis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relying on anything above ~20 kHz is asking for trouble, since you're in the roll-off region of the anti-aliassing filters. The response of these filters could easily change with different hardware releases. Also the transducers used in different models could have very different frequency responses, particularly once you get above ~15 kHz.

Comment: I understand that, yet it is a requirement for a specific situation. We've been through something similar on Android models, having some where it works and some where it doesn't. We just never expect that would happen with the iPhone, since it's been working perfectly until now. Even if it doesn't behave like iPhone 4 did, maybe it is still possible to work with the iPhone 4S, as long as it works with frequencies above 20.5 kHz, too.

Comment: Well relying on undocumented/unspecified behaviour is rather naïve - your product could easily end up dead in the water when the hardware changes - not a big problem for a hobby project, but suicidal for a business venture.

Comment: Are you setting `AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the kAudioSessionProperty_Mode doesn't seem to make different. The problem is really on the roll-off region, more precisely after 20.5 kHZ, where everything stats to get really bad (and low :P). Taking that into account, I wonder if it would be possible to disable the noise cancelation (and if that would really make any difference).

Answer (score 3):

The specification of both those iPhone models only states a frequency response up to 20 kHz.  Anything above that might be subject to change without notice, not only between models, but possibly also for a given model if Apple is sourcing mics from multiple vendors.  Furthermore, the roll-off behavior in both phase and frequency response between the 20 kHz limit and half the sampling rate can vary by a huge amount depending on the type and order of the anti-aliasing filters.

The frequency response can also vary depending on the direction of the sound and the directionality of the mic, which can also vary between mics and enclosures.

Comment: And the shape/material of the case will make things far more exciting...